# Looping through objects to get their properties in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to develop a game in Windows Phone. I'm a beginner using c# and xaml. In the xaml I've objects with the same properties only Tag property is different. What I want to do is to loop througth object tags and change for another object (image) if I find a specific tag.

I've tried some code, like this:

```
foreach(Image tag in img) //but it says:
```

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Windows.Ui.Xaml.Controls.Image' because 'Windows.Ui.Xaml.Controls.Image' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'...

Comment: `Image` is not a collection, so that makes sense. Honestly the whole use case sounds rather odd. Could you flesh out what you are trying to accomplish so we can suggest a better approach?

Comment: the error message is telling you exactly what is wrong .. if you are not familiar with `GetEnumerator` then just google it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since as a beginner you won't likely use MVVM and just leave everything in the View, what you can do is just cycle through the LayoutRoot. If you have other Panel in the layoutroot that contain images, you want to do it recursively:

```
MainPage()
{
    DoSomethingToImages(LayoutRoot);
}

DoSomethingToImages(Panel panel)
{
    foreach(Image img in panel.Children.Where(x=> x is Image))
    {
        DoSomething(img);
    }
    var panels = panel.Children.Where(x=> x is Panel);
    if (panels.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach(Panel p in panels)
        {
            DoSomethingToImages(p);
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand, this is obviously bad practice, and you would normally bind your images to your viewmodel. The only exception might be heavily customised user controls to make things work that'd be otherwise extremely time-consuming to work around with MVVM. (Note: I think that MVVM is not always necessary for custom controls, since many times all you want is some custom graphical behaviour, like a button that takes an Image Background for it's pressed state as well, and that stuff belongs to the view, but you can usually solve that with a dependency property in the view and some XAML tweaking. Also, separating the ViewModel for a custom control makes it a bit harder to copy it to another project if you put it inside your own project - you have to find the viewmodel as well! :) ).

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, you'll need a collection to loop through.
Personally, I like dictionaries.
Here's an example I think you might be able to modify for your own purposes.

This will enable you to "loop though object tags", however as [HighCore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643085/highcore) mentioned, it's probably not "the right way" to do whatever you're ultimately trying to accomplish.

```csh
        Image img1 = new Image();
        Image img2 = new Image();
        Image img3 = new Image();

        img1.Tag = "tag1";
        img2.Tag = "tag2";
        img3.Tag = "tag3";

        Dictionary<string, Image> ImgDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Image>();

        ImgDictionary.Add(img1.Tag.ToString(), img1);
        ImgDictionary.Add(img2.Tag.ToString(), img2);
        ImgDictionary.Add(img3.Tag.ToString(), img3);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Image> i in ImgDictionary)
        {
            // do stuff with i.Value or i.Key 
        }

        string tmp_TagName = "tag1";
        if (ImgDictionary.ContainsKey(tmp_TagName))
        {
            Image ReturnImage;
            ImgDictionary.TryGetValue(tmp_TagName, out ReturnImage);
            // do something with your ReturnImage...
        }
```

Comment: this is bad advice. You don't "dictionaries" the UI in XAML-based technologies. Instead, you use proper XAML to define the UI and DataBinding to interact with it.

Comment: @HighCore First: I agree with you. Second: the question wasn't about DataBinding, he just said `"I want to do is to loop througth object tags"`. And last, the OP has stated that he's a beginner, which means he's probably not about follow [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) right off the bat.